# Angular не собирает проект

Tags: angular

Установил Angular7.
Когда делал проект сам, Angular его создавал и собирал. Но собирать чужие не хочет.
Из папки проекта ввел:

```
ng serve
```

Angular написал

> An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'
>
> See "/tmp/ng-SCN5tZ/angular-errors.log" for further details.

После этого ввел

```
sudo npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular
sudo npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
ng serve
```

Ответ Angular

> Schema validation failed with the following errors:
>
> Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
>
> Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
>
> Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
>
> at MergeMapSubscriber._registry.compile.pipe.operators_1.concatMap.validator
>
> Result [as project] (/home/john/Загрузки/bekhterev-master/napp/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/workspace/workspace.js:198:42)
>
> at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (/home/john/Загрузки/bekhterev-master/napp/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:69:27)
>
> at MergeMapSubscriber._next (/home/john/Загрузки/bekhterev-master/napp/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:59:18)
>
> at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/home/john/Загрузки/bekhterev-master/napp/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:67:18)
>
> at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (/home/john/Загрузки/bekhterev-master/napp/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:92:26)
>
> at InnerSubscriber._next (/home/john/Загрузки/bekhterev-master/napp/node_modules/rxjs/internal/InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
>
> at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/home/john/Загрузки/bekhterev-master/napp/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:67:18)
>
> at MapSubscriber._next (/home/john/Загрузки/bekhterev-master/napp/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/map.js:55:26)
>
> at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/home/john/Загрузки/bekhterev-master/napp/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:67:18)
>
> at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (/home/john/Загрузки/bekhterev-master/napp/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:86:26)

Этот проект был сделан под Angular6

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "napp": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/napp",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/brain.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/dwv/decoders",
                "output": "/assets/dwv/decoders"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles-app-loading.scss",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": false
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "napp:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "napp:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "napp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "napp-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "napp:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "napp:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "napp"
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "napp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "start-https": "ng serve --ssl true --ssl-cert ./server.crt --ssl-key ./server.key",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "6.0.0-beta.18",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^14.0.0",
    "angular-auth-oidc-client": "^9.0.2",
    "angular-datatables": "^7.0.0",
    "angular6-json-schema-form": "^7.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "cornerstone-core": "^2.2.8",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.19",
    "docx": "^4.7.1",
    "dwv": "^0.25.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng2-completer": "^2.0.8",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^1.3.5",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.1.4",
    "ngx-toastr": "^9.1.1",
    "ngx-ui-loader": "^7.1.0-beta.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.3",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.14.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "2.9.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: ты установил версию `@angular-devkit/build-angular` которая совместима с angular 9, а не 6. Ищи  версию, которая совместима с 6

Answer (score 1):

Должно помочь `npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.6.1`